# How to add input field values in a single line in terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, terminal

**Problem**

In Linux and Mac there is a time when we need to enter some input to the shell after which the command gets executed. I have multiple commands as listed below

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 && (so on)
```

After some respective commands there will be a time where we need to enter some text field.

How can we achieve it.

**Most probably I am using -y but there can be multiple fields In single command**

Like enter name, age , etc

Comment: Please concretise this part: *we need to enter some text field*

Comment: `read -p`? See `help read`.

Comment: You can use `https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect`